# c++ undefined rererence in opencv findHomography() function

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I tried running the code snippet in the following opencv/c++ example http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html#gsc.tab=0

Part of the code is given below:

```
 std::vector<Point2f> obj;
 std::vector<Point2f> scene;
 for( size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
 {
   //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
   obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
   scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
 }
 Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, RANSAC );
```

I get the following compile error

```
 /home/yudori/Documents/qt_projects/featureTest/main.cpp:57: error: undefined reference to `cv::findHomography(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, double, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double)'
```

on the line

```
 Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, RANSAC );
```

I checked the "calib3d.hpp" header file and it seems to contain similar declarations for the findHomography function but I can't help but think I'm missing something. I am running opencv 3.1.0 on Ubuntu and I'm fairly new to c++, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on linux add this to your compile string -lopencv_calib3d and if you are working on windows and visual studio, add opencv_calib3d in Additional Libraries